# Angular 2: Google Maps click event not updating data bound HTML

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic-framework, data-binding

I read a bunch of other overflow questions regarding this, but none of them seemed to help. I have a Google Map with markers. When they are clicked, they change the value of `selected` to return which of the markers is currently selected. The click event does what it's supposed to, it properly updates `selected`, however, it doesn't update the bound html.

Here is my code:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'map-view',
  templateUrl: 'mapview.html'
})

export class MapView
{
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private eventService: EventService){}


  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  markers: any;
  selected: any;
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------



  ngOnInit() //Angular LifeCycle Hook
  {
    //initialization for map and markers not shown
    this.selected = markers[0]; //sets default selected to the first marker
    initClicking();
  }



  //this all works perfectly. It changes "selected" to the marker that was clicked
  initClicking() 
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++)
    {
      google.maps.event.addListener(this.markers[i], 'click', ((i) =>{
        return () =>
        {
          this.selected = this.events[i];
        }
      })(i));
    }
  }

}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
 <p>{{selected.title}}<p>
```

The weird thing is that it always works for the initialization of `this.selected = markers[0];`, but not after that.

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?